# Access to Avro schema version when using SpringBoot @KafkaHandler

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, avro

I'm using a SpringBoot Kafka Consumer with Avro Deserialization like this:

```
Service
@KafkaListener(topics = ["\${app.topics.foo}"])
class FooConsumer(private val fooImportService: FooImportService) {

    @KafkaHandler
    fun consume(@Payload fooKopf: FooKopf, @Header(name = "X-Foo") foo: String) {
        // ...
    }
```

Can I somehow access the Avro Schema name and version that was used to deserialize a spefic message?

It seems not to be part of the message Header nor can I access it via the ConsumerRecord class.
Anything else like "@Schema" that I could add to the method parameter list?

Comment: Are you using a schema registry ? And io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer ?

Comment: @benbenw yes, exactly

Comment: You want the schema used to deserialize the avro record (here FooKopf) or the one used to serialize on the producer side ? You probably already have the Schema for deserialization in your avro mapping code : see SCHEMA$ in the avro generated code.

Comment: If the producer introduces changes, the Avro Registry automatically assigns a new version number to the Schema. My client code does not seem to honor this version number, it always deserializes into the class I generated locally with the Gradle Plugin using the FooKopf.avsc file. I want to know if I have the chance to see the Avro Schema version number before deciding the record should be a FooKopf or FooKopfv2 object.

Comment: you usually have one record mapping on the consumer side, if the producer use another version of the Schema it should be compatible (the registry can check that point see https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html#compatibility-types)